# install laravel 5.5 error

Tags: php, laravel

I want install laravel 5.5 on linux ubuntu 16
Run this command .

php version is 7.0 
and all Requirements modules are installed

```
$composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

And i have error

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.28)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.28)
    Loading from cache

    Created project in blog
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - symfony/thanks v1.0.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
        - symfony/thanks v1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
        - Installation request for symfony/thanks ^1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/thanks[v1.0.0, v1.0.1].

    Potential causes:
     - A typo in the package name
     - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
       see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

    Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2324 might be of some help. Then main suggestion is to run `composer update`

Comment: have you tried running `php composer.phar self-update` first? I would also try `composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "*" --prefer-dist`

Answer (score 2):

Remove your composer cache first. 
run `composer clearcache` and `composer self-update`

Hope this helps.